# Photos shared for marriage proposals

Tags: nikah, photos, culture

In an arranged marriage setting, can we send girl's picture without head scarf to a potential suitor's mother/sister.. not knowing for sure if they will delete the photo if not interested.
The family of the suitors have stated many times that they will come to the house for further talk if they like the girl.. which is acceptable in Islam as well. They have the right to see whom they are choosing for their son.
If we do not send without hijab pics.. they do not reply and the matter gets closed.. many proposals are going because of this.. please elaborate on this.

JazakAllahu khairan

Comment: Well... these photos are being shared to a women, so why not?

Comment: agreeing to @NanoAdam. I suppose this would be the same if the "potential suitor's mother/sister" directly meet the girl face to face without the girl's scarf.

Comment: The to be husband is allowed to see from the woman he might consider for marriage at least, hands, face and even hair according the majority view he only can send a female relative to see her and describe her shape for him. There's even a view going so far to allow him to see whatever he is able to get to see from this woman... However the main issue here is the photos sent. You should let the opposite party agree upon deleting the photos if they don't intend to go further steps.